# Express session stored in redis for anonymous

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

I'm using express 4.0 with module `express-session`, `connect-redis` and `passport` for manage sessions. Everything is ok for login and logout, I can retrieve session etc.

But I've noticed something weird: even when I'm anonymous, if I'm going to redis and type:

```
$ KEYS *
```

Redis return an entry `1) "sess:VWdwTjPXkITmqQ77xI8cotlltdrz7S8s"` even if nobody is currently connected. When I'm connect, this key is replaced by another corresponding to my session. And when I'm logout, the key changes again by another. When the anonymous user call an URL, my `req.sessionID` is also set.

In this site https://engineering.linkedin.com/nodejs/blazing-fast-nodejs-10-performance-tips-linkedin-mobile I've read something about create session even for anonymous (7. Go session-free) and I think it's related.

I add the middlewhere in the main app.js file with something like:

```
var
  passport = require('passport'),
  User = require('../models/user'),
  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
  session = require('express-session'),
  RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore(app.locals.services.session.config),
  secret: 'mysecretstring'
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

I have the problem even if I start from a fresh server and if I try to GET the homepage where I'm doing nothing:

```
index: function (req, res) {
  res.render('home/index');
}
```

Even in this case, a new key is created in my redis.

**Note:**
If I remove both lines, no key are created.

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

So, my question is: How to avoid a key creation in Redis for anonymous users ? (and, is it a good idea to not store a session for anonymous ?).

Thanks !

Comment: It depends on the `express-session` configuration and how/where this middleware is added to your middleware chain.

Comment: Yep, sorry, forgot to add the sample. My question is updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a new session to be created for each request, set [`saveUninitialized`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#saveuninitialized) to `false` in the `express-session` middleware:

```
app.use(session({
  store             : new RedisStore(app.locals.services.session.config),
  secret            : 'mysecretstring',
  saveUninitialized : false,
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, but because I'm using PassportJS, this doesn't solve my problem: https://github.com/expressjs/session#saveuninitialized

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you mean by "anonymous", then. Can you elaborate that in your question? And perhaps also show a route for which a session is created even when it shouldn't.

Comment: If a new user comes to the website, even if the user is anonymous (not logged in Passport), a new key is created in redis . I don't want to create a new key in redis for all my anonymous users, in production is not very great for my memory.

Comment: @user1853777 I understand the problem. If your (anonymous) users aren't hitting any routes that are "protected" by Passport, I don't think they would get a session key. But without more code (for example, a route that a user may be following that is creating a session when it shouldn't) it's difficult to pinpoint the exact reason why it's happening.

Comment: Ok, question updated. Let me know if something is still missing.

Comment: @user1853777 I can't reproduce with that setup _and_ `saveUnitialized` set to `false`: there are no session cookies being pushed nor are new keys being created in Redis. Are you sure the client you're testing with isn't _sending_ a session cookie that was previously stored?

Comment: Even with the option `saveUnitialized` and without any cookie, when I GET the home page, the key is also created (and also a cookie). This is not related to `passport.session()` middleware initialization in app.js ?

Comment: @user1853777 I don't think so, no. AFAIK that will only do something if there's an actual active session ([testing code here](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/4d77a7dde58d2bc73e79)).

Comment: Arf... Don't understand... We have something very similar and I've still a cookie and a key creation. I've updated my question: when I remove both lines about passport middleware, it seems to work